# Strange warning when try to return array

Tags: objective-c

Heey

When I'm trying to return a array I'm always  getting this strange  "waring" message but it does not interrupt my App

**Returning 'ABRecordRef' (aka 'const void *') from a function with result type 'ABRecordRef *' (aka 'const void **') discards qualifiers**

Here is my code where I'm getting this message

```
- (ABRecordRef *) findContactsContainingName: (NSString *) fname
{
    //TODO: add lastname, phonenumber etc.

    // Load the contacts
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, nil);
    NSArray *thePeople = (__bridge NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

    for (id person in thePeople){
        NSString *firstname = (__bridge NSString*) ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)(person), kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        if([firstname isEqualToString: fname]){
            return (__bridge ABRecordRef)(person);
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Can someone please explain me why I get here a Waring ..

Thanks for help and fast answer

Comment: I guess this is because of your `return NULL`

Comment: @gasparuff nope it not

Comment: Ok, then maybe because if the `*`, as Martin R already answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `*` here:

```
- (ABRecordRef *) findContactsContainingName: (NSString *) fname
               ^
```

`ABRecordRef` is already defined as a pointer.

Comment: But note that there are some "potential leaks" in your code. You should run "Product -> Analyze"!

Comment: @Mingebag: Why don't you try it yourself first? Run "Product -> Analyze". If you click on the small blue icons, you will get a detailed report about the problem. - If you cannot fix it at all I will help you (-:

Answer (score 1):

`ABRecord` is C API and it work in CoreFoundation ways.

In CoreFoundation (and AddressBook) objects are implemented as C structs, and pointers are used to reference them. A string in CoreFoundation is `CFStringRef`, which is interchangeable (or rather, toll-free bridged) with Foundation object, `NSString *`. (i.e. the "`Ref`" in `CFStringRef` implied a `*` in it - think it as `CFString *`, or rather `struct __CFString *`)

Similarly, `ABRecordRef` is `ABRecord *` and hence your return type, `ABRecordRef *` is actually `ABRecord **`, a secondary pointer. This is what the compiler is complaining.

You can check out the source code of GNUstep CoreBase and you will find out why. GNUstep is a open-source clone of Cocoa (it predates Cocoa!) for Linux and studying its source code can be very helpful on understanding how Cocoa work under the hood.